# py2app won't open on other computers

Tags: python, macos, py2app

I created a app w/ py2app. It opens and runs fine on my computer, however when I try to send it to another computer it won't open. The OSX dock looksl ike an open is about to expand for the app icon, then it minimizes again.

Py2app is compiling the app with the main py file and a csv file. The other computer that can't open the py2app file was able to run the main.py file without issue opening it via terminal.

This is my first time using py2app, so any guidance would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Do you see any error messages? Can you bundle debugging information into your app? Possibly the python interpreter built with your app is not present on the other computer?

Comment: @SenthilKumaran I did use a 'try:/except Exception as e:', and nothing was returned. I don't believe the interperter is the case, as they can run the .py file not compiled via terminal, and even on the computer it's built on, if I upload the .app to dropbox as a zip then redownload on the same computer it has the same issue. When trying to open the uploaded/downloaded version I get an OSX prompt about opening an app downloaded from the internet and I can see the app icon in the dock. Once I click 'open' the icon disappears and won't open.